# How do I set a dictionary size for Activator.CreateInstance?

Tags: c#

I want to set the initial size of a dictionary using Activator.CreateInstance, what is the syntax please?

```
var collection = Activator.CreateInstance(someDictionaryType) as IDictionary;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to call a [`Dictionary` constructor with an int parameter representing capacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk84bxf4.aspx), pass an `object` array with a single element - the size:

```
var collection = Activator.CreateInstance(someDictionaryType, new object[] {123}) as IDictionary;
```